# Enqueued style and script is not working in my wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Only my custom style and script is not working in my plugin file.

```
add_action('init', 'register_script');

function register_script() {
    wp_register_script('bootstrapjs','http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js' );

    wp_register_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' );

    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('/js/script.js', __FILE__));

    wp_register_style('style','http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    wp_register_style('new_style',plugins_url('/css/new_style.css',__FILE__) );

    // enqueing all scripts and styles.
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs' );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
}
```

Here only `new-style` and `custom-jquery` is not working in my plugin. What i am doing wrong i can't understand can anyone explain? I have tried it in various ways. But not working. If I use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead `init` then none of this styles and scripts is working.

As i am very new to wordpress some example code will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`plugin_url( $path )`should not have a leading slash. The reason your scripts and stylesheets won't load is most likely because there's a double slash in the URL.

```php
wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url( 'js/script.js', __FILE__ ) );
wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url( 'css/new_style.css',__FILE__ ) );
```

Comment: the problems was not with the leading slash. But i got  it.Both leading slash or not work just fine.